# list named with a function argument in python

Tags: python, list, arguments

I get the feeling this is probably something I should know but I can't think of it right now. I'm trying to get a function to build a list where the name of the list is an argument given in the function;

e.g.

```
def make_hand(deck, handname):
    handname = []
    for c in range(5):
        handname.append(deck.pop())
    return handname

    # deck being a list containing all the cards in a deck of cards earlier
```

The issue is that this creates a list called handname when i want it to be called whatever the user enters as handname when creating the hand.

Anyone can help? thanks

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a good idea. :) Try using a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep a dictionary where the keys are the name of the hand and the values are the list.

Then you can just say dictionary[handname] to access a particular hand. Along the lines of:

```
hands = {} # Create a new dictionary to hold the hands.
hands["flush"] = make_hand(deck) # Generate some hands using your function.
hands["straight"] = make_hand(deck) # Generate another hand with a different name.
print hands["flush"] # Access the hand later.
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can create variables with arbitrary names at runtime, using `exec` (as sykora suggested), or by meddlings with `locals`, `globals` or `setattr` on objects, your question is somewhat moot.

An object (just about anything, from integers to classes with 1000 members) is just a chunk of memory. It does not have *a* name, it can have arbitrarily many names, and all names are treated equal: they just introduce a reference to some object and prevent it from being collected.

If you want to name items in the sense that a user of your program gives a user-visible name to an object, you should use a dictionary to associated objects with names.

Your approach of user-supplied variable names has several other severe implications:
 * what if the user supplies the name of an existing variable?
 * what if the user supplies an invalid name?

You're introducing a [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html), so unless it is really, really important for the purpose of your program that the user can specify a new variable name, the user should not have to worry about how you store your objects - an not be presented with seemingly strange restrictions.